# View my cases and all new cases (other owner)

Tags: case, permissions, list-view, filters, service

as an agent I need to see the tickets I managed (the owner is me) and also the new tickets (other owner). I tried to filter in the lists of views but it doesn't allow me to do what I want. Any suggestion?. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, are the cases generally shared across all users in your org? What is the sharing rules for the cases? Also, can you share screenshots of the filter if the sharing is public?

Comment: There is no sharing rule yet and the cases have a record type.

Comment: can you share screenshot of the filter?